# Filter a List and return the response from a CompletableFuture java async operation

Tags: java, filter, completable-future

Hello I have to filter and return the result of a CompletableFuture and store it in an object variable to work with this object after the filter, the Completable method which extract the list from the database is and is located in the salonService is :

```
public CompletableFuture<List<SalonDTO>> listAllSalons() {
        return salonRepository.findAllAsync()
                .thenApply(salonList -> ObjectMapperUtils.mapAll(salonList, salonDTO.class));
}
```

Then I'm trying to filter the info in the next way:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<SalonDTO>> listKidsByGuardian1() {
        return salonService.listAll()
                .thenApply(salonDTOList -> {
                    findsalonByChildAge(salonDTOList);
                    return salonDTOList;
                });
}

private SalonDTO findsalonByChildAge(List<SalonDTO> salonDTOList) {
       salonDTOList.stream()
       .filter(salon -> salon.getMinAge() > 13);
}
```

I'm not pretty familiar with the CompletableFuture class, so I don't understand how Can I get a simple object from this async operation. Besides that it is not easy to debug these async methods. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Side comment: it would be more efficient to put the condition in your query rather than downloading lots of useless records from your DB and filtering them after the fact.

Comment: In fact, there are a few of them, there are only six registers.